# Copy constructor's member initializer not requiring a member

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

This is my class:
(I know currently it violates the rule of three because it doesn't yet have an explicitly defined copy assignment operator.)

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class die
{
private:
    int sideCount;
    T* valueOfSides;
public:
    die() : sideCount(0), valueOfSides(nullptr) {}
    die(int sideCount, T* valueOfSides) : sideCount(sideCount), valueOfSides(nullptr)
    {
        this->valueOfSides = new T[sideCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < sideCount; ++i)
            this->valueOfSides[i] = valueOfSides[i];
    }

    die(const die& that) : sideCount(that.sideCount), valueOfSides(nullptr) //<- WARNING
    {
        valueOfSides = new T[sideCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < sideCount; ++i)
            valueOfSides[i] = that.valueOfSides[i];
    }

    void printValueOfSides() //Unrelated but I will leave this method here if you decide to use it
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sideCount; ++i)
            std::cout << "valuesOfSides[" << i << "] = " << valueOfSides[i] << std::endl;
    }

    ~die() { delete[] valueOfSides; }
};
```

The warning at the copy constructor's initializer list is:
`die(const die& that) : sideCount(that.sideCount), valueOfSides(nullptr)<-here`
**The value** (I'm guessing `nullptr`) **is never used.** When I remove `valueOfSides(nullptr)` from the **copy constructor's initializer list** the warning goes away. I know code works without it but for the sake of completion when a die object is created using the **copy constructor**

```
int main()
{
    die<int> d1(4, array);
    die<int> d2(d1);

    return 0;
}
```

I want it first to be **initialized** with the `nullptr` then **assigned** to the values in the constructor's parameter. As its being done with the parameterized constructor.
So my questions are:

- Why do I get this warning In the **copy constructor** but not In the **parameterized constructor**?
- I include `valueOfSides` pointer in the member initializer of all the constructors for the sake of completion and because I believe it is good practice to **initialize** the members even though they will get **assigned** in the body of the constructor. Is this a good practice or a habit? Or should I just give up Initializing `valuesOfSides` when it is not necessary to initialize? In this case, only include it in the member initializer of the default constructor and not in the parameterized and copy constructor?
- For my second question, Am I accurate with my depictions of **initialization** and **assignment** of **members**?
- **Update:** I tried the same code on visual studio 2019 0 warnings 0 errors. It might be IDE related, I originally got this warning using cLion(mingW compiler)

Comment: `valueOfSides(nullptr)` is almost immediately undone with `valueOfSides = new T[sideCount];`, so the compiler's right. I'd use `valueOfSides( new T[sideCount])` in the initializer list and remove the assignment from the body.

Comment: No clue why you get the warning in one case and not the other. Sometimes what's picked off by static analyzers can be weird.

Comment: I recomend using `std::vector` instead of the old C style array. Your code will become much simpler this way.

Comment: @user4581301 I'm still getting **The value is never used**  warning at the ```valueOfSides( new T[sideCount])```

Comment: But "almost immediately" is not "atomic". The `new` can fail and then the destructor gets called and `valueOfSides` would be undefined. There would be no way to know whether to delete it or not. So I believe the `nullptr` is required. gcc and clang don't warn about it.

Comment: @wohlstad I'm still oblivious to the vectors at the moment, no idea on what they are and how to use them, I will look into them though thanks for the suggestion, also im trying to understand the logic behind it. The code works either way.

Comment: You can use `T* valueOfSides{nullptr};` and let the compiler worry about it.

Comment: It isn't used. Before anything can so much as look at `valueOfSides` and see that it's a null pointer, it's value is changed. The compiler is just telling you you're wasting time and odds are it'll optimize out the stop-over at `nullptr`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow They are not wrong. The behavior of the code shown is equivalent with or without the `nullptr` initializer.

Comment: @nyms1 - I'll write an answer with an example how you can use `std::vector` in your case.

Comment: regardless of what I initialize ```valuesOfSides``` with in the copy constructor's member initializer the compiler keep's giving the warning. The value is never used

Comment: Warnings are diagnostics for things the compiler thinks are suspicious but aren't necessarily wrong. In this case, it is true the initialization is not necessary. But in practice it is likely not causing any harm (I would expect the compiler to optimize this well) and can be seen as a means of future-proofing your code to guard against easy mistakes.

Comment: You should try to only ask 1 question per post. Otherwise, you make it hard for anyone to provide an answer and risk the question being closed for lack of focus.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I stand corrected. I was sure the destructor would be called once the member initializer list was processed and the body throws an exception. But the lifetime of the object hasn't started until the end of the body.

Comment: It might be worth making a virtual base class for dies of any kind and a derived class where the sides are template parameter. That way a function taking a die argument can specify if it can use any die or wants a specific die, like a `D20`.

Comment: [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/7WMscWrs5), please include [mcve] (if it's not) and the compiler config.

Comment: Side note: If a constructor fails to complete, the object never existed and technically is not destroyed. The destructor does not run. It won't be an issue here, but if, say, you used `new` twice and the second `new` failed, you'd have to write code to clean up manually and `delete` the object you got from the first `new`. `new` is pretty hard to use correctly, and that's why it should be used sparingly. I personally consider it a disservice to students to require its use before teaching most of a first year C++ course so that the students can better understand the dangers and alternatives.

Comment: It's kind of like teaching multiplication before addition.

Comment: Using new once for each constructor(parameterized, copy) the program works fine I just dont get how the warning is produced how can a value in the initialization list  of the copy constructor can not be used.

Comment: Think of it like this simpler case: `int x = 0; x = 42;`. `x` cannot, legally, used while its value is 0. The compiler may warn you that setting the value to 0 is a waste of time, it might simply omit the assignment and produce the same output as `int x = 42;`, and it could do any combination or absolutely nothing.

Comment: @user4581301Yes, that makes sense but how come that only applies to the copy constructor, same situation applys to my parameterized constructor in this case but no warnings, Im starting to think its because of my IDE, I will try in visual studio 2019 now.

Comment: @user4581301I just tried it on visual studio 2019 and 0 warnings, I will take it as a specific warning to cLion I guess. Unless someone who knows how this exactly works at lower levels claims otherwise.

Comment: I have no clue why it catches one and not the other, but C++ is a stupidly complicated language and sometimes things just get missed. Many IDES have a static analysis tool built into them that tries to warn you of problems without compiling or of problems that compiler generally don't issue warnings for. In Visual Studio it's called intellisense. Eclipse calls theirs CODAN. I have no idea what CLion calls their tool or what it checks for. Generally I see it as a bonus when they spot a problem, but when they raise a false positive that I can't turn off... Anger Management time

Answer (score 3):

**Regarding the warning:**
As you can see in [@FrançoisAndrieux's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425577/copy-constructors-member-initializer-not-requiring-a-member/72425755#comment127945400_72425577) (and other comments), compiler warning are not necessarity issued for things that are wrong, but rather to any piece of code that seems suspicous. Your compiler determined the initialization to `nullptr` is superfluous and gave you a legitimate warning. You can chooce whether to remove this initialization.

**However:**
In C++ it is recomeded **not** to use old C style arrays.
Instead you can use either [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) for a fixed size array, or [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) for a dynamic size one (like in your case).

Using `std::vector` offers a lot of advantages. One of the most important is automatic memory management, so you don't have to manually call `new` and `delete`.
Also the constructors and assignment operators of `std::vector` will allow you to shift from the **rule of five** to the **rule of zero** ([The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

This is how your code above will look like using `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <class T>
class die
{
private:
    std::vector<T> m_valueOfSides;
public:
    die() = default;
    die(std::vector<T> const & valueOfSides) : m_valueOfSides(valueOfSides) {}

    void printValueOfSides() //Unrelated but I will leave this method here if you decide to use it
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < sideCount; ++i)
            std::cout << "valuesOfSides[" << i << "] = " << valueOfSides[i] << std::endl;
    }

    // NOTE: copy ctor and the rest from the rule of five are not needed.
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> arr{ 1,2,3,4 };
    die<int> d1(arr);
    die<int> d2(d1);
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see it became **a lot shorter, and less error-prone**.

Comment: There is also a third option which is less well known, when you need a fixed size container whose size is only known at runtime. You can use a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` to safely own a pointer to an array which you can create using `std::make_unique<int[]>(n);` to create `int[]` array with `n` elements. However, it isn't a proper container, you can't iterate over it, and the size is still separate. But it may be applicable here, since `sideCount` seems constant for a given instance, and the array is a hidden implementation detail.

Comment: @AnoopRana I commented above about the usage of `std::vector` and the OP said they are not familiar with it and seemed interested, so I offered to write an asnwer demonstrating how to use it in this case. Using `std::vector` will eliminate the cause for the issue to begin with.

Comment: @wholstad I'm still getting several warnings on my compiler, no idea what they are but thanks alot for the alternative solution! I will make sure I refer to this when I start learning about the vectors.

Comment: @user4581301 although my answer was just elaborating on my comment above, I agree that for completness the issue of the warning has to be mentioned so I added it.

Comment: @wohlstad I see, so many comment were there that it was easy to miss some. Deleting my old comment now, as OP also wants to see the alternative solution.

Comment: The explanation of the warning is not quite correct.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @wohlstad see my answer below

Comment: Scratch that, I was looking at the wrong constructor

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I got confused as well. It's been some time since I originally answered... so I believe my description is ok. Anyway my main point was the  recomendation to use better language elements like std::vector etc.